# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action returned undefined React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am not sure why I get the error. Unhandled Rejection (Error): Given action "SET_CARS", reducer "cars" returned undefined. To ignore an action, you must explicitly return the previous state. If you want this reducer to hold no value, you can return null instead of undefined.

REDUCERS

```
  import { SET_CARS} from "../actions";
  import { combineReducer } from "redux";

  function cars(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case SET_CARS:
  return 
  action.items;
  default:
  return state; }
  }

 const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 cars
 });

 export default rootReducer;
```

ACTIONS

```
 export const SET_CARS = 'SET_CARS';

 export function setCars(items){
  return {
    type: SET_CARS , 
    items
}
}
```

SearchCars

```
class SearchCars extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();


   this.state = {
  tansmition: ""
  };
  }

search() {
let { tansmition } = this.state;
const url = `http://localhost:4000/vehicles/? 
transmission=${tansmition}`;


fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET'
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
    this.props.setCars(json.results)
  })
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fetch` is missing a `return` in it's fat arrow function and thus the fetch is not returning anything.

Change this line:

```
.then(json => {
    this.props.setCars(json.results)
})
```

To this:

```
.then(json => {
    return this.props.setCars(json.results)
})
```

Comment: .then(json => {
       return this.props.setCars(json.results)
       }). STILL GIVES ERROR

Answer (score 2):

[ASI strikes again.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi)

```
return 
action.items;
```

This gets interpreted as:

```
return;
action.items;
```

Put them together on one line and it should work. I'd also consider using a formatter like [prettier](https://prettier.io). It'll help yourself and others looking at your code to see bugs like this more easily.